# How to repair malformed XML?

Tags: php, xml

What is best practice to repair malformed XML files with PHP? For example CDATA part contains illegal chars.  With regular expressions? Or execute some Linux command line tools?

Comment: This question is pretty *vague*, maybe you should specify in depth the kind of malformed documents you have to deal with. XML is **extremely** general in scope, so a general solution is not really feasible.

Comment: XML parsers are pretty strict, some preprocessing sometimes may easen that, but to get an answer you need to provide more details. A far fetched guess: with **XML** do you really mean, maybe, **XHTML**?

Comment: "with regular expressions?" Certainly not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Comment: thanks, specifically, there are problem with illegal chars (unescaped entities) i.e <root><info><title>Me myself & I</title></info></root>
sometimes also directly fetched and unescaped HTML code  <root><info><content>Some <b>important</b> content here</content></info></root>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Tidy**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)

> Tidy is a binding for the Tidy HTML
>   clean and repair utility which allows
>   you to not only clean and otherwise
>   manipulate HTML documents, but also
>   traverse the document tree.

```
// Specify configuration
$config = array(
           'indent'     => true,
           'input-xml'  => true,
           'output-xml' => true,
           'wrap'       => false);
// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseFile('sample.xml', $config);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
// Output
echo $tidy;
```

Comment: This is perfect. But I need to  save the repaired string into a file. I tried `file_put_contents("new.xml",$tidy)` but new.xml file is created with no contents.