# Fixing quote error in invalid XML

Tags: php, xml, string

A remote service generates invalid XML with attribute values without quotation marks. Example:

```
<abc invalid=105 valid="105">
```

In PHP, how can I patch up such errors in the output? Just passing it to SimpleXML results in an error.

Thanks.

Comment: Will this not sort attributes? http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.isxml.php

Comment: I would contact the admin of the remote service ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797100/how-to-repair-malformed-xml/3797486#3797486

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [tidy](http://php.net/tidy):

```
$input = '<abc invalid=105 valid="105">';
$tidy = new tidy();
$config = array('output-xml' => true);
$cleanXML = $tidy->repairString($input, $config);
```

Comment: That would be a perfect solution iif my miserable web host supported tidy.