# Locating a < symbol in HTML that isn't part of a tag

Tags: php, html, dom, xml-parsing, pdflib

I'm trying to find a way to reliably locate and replace `<` and `>` symbols within an HTML/XML formatted string that do not belong to tags.

Basically I start with an HTML string and convert it into something usable by PDFLib, which uses a form of XML to describe documents to be written as PDF's.  However if there is a `<` within in the content it sees it as the opening of a tag and throws a parse exception.

#### Example input:

```
<p>This is a test where 6 < 9</p>
<p>This is part of <strong>The same test</strong></p>
<p>This should also work 6<99999</p>
```

The text surrounding the `<` is not always numbers, it is user entered and could be anything such as `Grade<C`, `Blue<Red<Green`, `Test < Test2`.... just about anything really

#### Required output

```
This is a test where 6 <charref fontname=Helvetica encoding=unicode>&lt;<resetfont> 9\n
This is part of <fontname=Helvetica fontstyle=bold encoding=unicode>The same test<resetfont>\n
This should also work 6<charref fontname=Helvetica encoding=unicode>&lt;<resetfont>99999\n
```

I've tried a `str_replace` and `preg_replace`, but can't find a solution that will reliably leave the tags alone and replace just the `<` in context.

Parsing the DOM also seems to fail as the `DOMDocument` sees the `<` as an opening tag as well

Using `htmlspecialchars` on the string converts all the tags `<>` into `&lt;&gt;` as well which is no good.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should use `&lt;&gt;` in the rendered HTML. Why can't you do it this way?

Comment: Try the answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797100/how-to-repair-malformed-xml

Comment: @cheesemacfly because it won't be rendered HTML.. its going to be converted into a form of XML and used to generate a PDF

Comment: Why can't you replace `&lt;` with `<charref fontname=Helvetica encoding=unicode>&lt;<resetfont>` once you have used `htmlspecialchars`? I might be missing something but I don't see the issue.

Comment: @cheesemacfly `<strong>6 < 7</strong>` becomes `&lt;strong&gt;6 &lt; 7&lt;/strong&gt;` which when replacing the `&lt;` with the PDFLib code breaks the `strong` tag completely

Comment: Ok, see your point. I though you were running `htmlspecialchars` only on the content and not on the whole HTML

Comment: @TimStamp put that as an answer if you want and I'll accept it.  I used the Tidy lib to parse the html first and it worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the answer from this question:

[how to repair malformed xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797100/how-to-repair-malformed-xml)

I tried to add this as as it stands, but StackOverflow requires me to add some description to the answer, or it automatically gets converted into a comment, which can't be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

try reading the string from start char by char if it encounters a < push it in a buffer if > is found without a space then its a tag else if it encounter a < again mark the previous as < and put next in buffer ... and repeat until the end of string

Comment: you'll also have to push quotes into the stack, to avoid situations like `<abbr title="<silly tag>">`

Comment: Tried this out and it did work, but the `Tidy` suggestion by @TimStamp was a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0):

While it's no longer maintained, I think [the php port of html5lib](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-php) is probably your best bet for parsing bad markup.

A simple call like this:

```
require_once 'your-path-path-to-html5lib/Parser.php';
$dom = HTML5_Parser::parse($input);
```

will take bad markup in `$input` and return a valid php [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

From there you can save it back to a string with `$dom->saveHTML()` or `$dom->saveXML`, or extract the bits you want with the DOM API.

Note that this will produce a full HTML document with `head` and `body` etc. even if your original data didn't include that.

If you just want to parse an HTML fragment, you can do:

```
$dom = HTML5_Parser::parseFragment($input);
```

which will return a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).

Answer (score 0):

HTML entities are the best way to do such things `&lt;&gt;` are the entities used to replace `<>` in HTML. Even using the `<code>` tag. You can use these entities and replace them with `<>` in your HTML Tags. `www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp`